# Linear harmonic oscillators

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

When we find the solutions of the differential equations leading to the expression for displacement of a body in SHM as a corollary we derive that $\omega=2\pi/T$, Now from what I make out considering it as a projection of circular motion , the body always subtends equal angle at the origin every second or the angle subtended by a body is always integral multiples of $\omega$. Now my question is how is this omega constant because the displacement per second covered by body will keep on decreasing as force is proportional to distance. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You yourself conceded that you are projecting uniform circular motion in phase space to coordinate space. The force and potential energy  oscillates sinusoidally, out of phase with the kinetic energy which likewise oscillates. It should be in your book.

Comment: I am asking why is the angular frequency constant?

Comment: ? Uniform circular motion not good enough for you?

Comment: But why are we associating it with uniform circular motion?

Comment: Because that's what it is, ***in phase space***, no? Write down the equations describing it, on the x,p plane. You already declared that's what you are projecting.

Comment: I am still not clear. I understand the math but I want to know the intuitive reason.

Comment: Geometry is intuition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142708/discussion-between-thecuriousone-and-cosmas-zachos).

Comment: I've added to my answer to try to answer your  queries.

Comment: What was the reason for downvote?

Comment: $~\omega~$ is constant because m and k both are constant

Comment: I know the math but I was asking how was it arrived at intuitively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

" how is this omega constant because the displacement per second covered by body will keep on decreasing as force is proportional to distance." Imagine a point, P,  going round a circular path with constant angular velocity, $\omega$, about the circle centre. Now visualise the projection, Q, on to, say, the vertical diameter, of this moving point. Q will move fast when it is near the circle centre, and more and more slowly as it approaches the end of the diameter – and so on. In other words the motion of Q will be the same as that of a mass on a spring performing simple harmonic motion, even though $\omega$ is constant.

That $\omega$ really *is* constant follows inescapably from the mathematics, specifically that the solution to the Newton's law equation,
$$m\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=-kx,$$
is
$$x=A\sin(\omega t +\phi)$$
in which $\omega=\sqrt{k/m}$ and is a constant because $k$ and $m$ are constants. $A$ and $\phi$ are arbitrary constants.

By definition $A\sin \theta$ is the $y$ coordinate of the point at angle $\theta$ round a circle of radius $A$ (centred on the origin) from the +$x$ axis. Therefore $A\sin(\omega t +\phi)$ is the $y$ coordinate of a point on the circle at angle $(\omega t + \phi)$ to the +$x$ axis). But this angle increases by $\omega$ radians per unit time, that is $\omega$ is the point's angular velocity. Hence the projection approach discussed above.

Comment: Could you explain what happens(excluding math) if we assume the SHM to be a non uniform motion? And what would be its complications

Comment: What, I wonder, do you mean by "a non-uniform motion"? I would call SHM, as given by $x=A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$, non-uniform as the velocity keeps changing over each cycle. We don't, in any case, have any choice over what we can *assume* about SHM, as the motion has to obey $x=A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$, or it won't be SHM !

Comment: Have you studied the displacement-time graph and velocity-time graph for a body doing SHM? And – a question that must surely be asked – do you have a **textbook** that deals with SHM?

Comment: Yes I have. Ok a better way to put the question  is why omega=sqrtk/m

Comment: We are **defining** $\omega$ to be $\sqrt{(k/m)}$. What, I suspect, is giving you difficulty is the interpretation of $\omega$ as an angular velocity. To understand this you need to understand the mathematics that shows why $x=A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$ is a solution of the Newton's second law equation $m \frac{d_2x}{dt^2}=-kx$.  My answer deals with the meaning or interpretation of $A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$.

Comment: Your textbook should explain all this stuff. It should certainly have told you that we *define* $\omega^2$ as $k/m$. It should also deal with why $x=A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$ is the solution to the Newton's second law equation and with how to interpret $x=A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$. The last of these is perhaps the hardest, which is why I concentrated on it in my answer.

Comment: My textbook just states the equation and does not derive it. As it’s derivation is above my grades level.

Comment: "above your grades level" perhaps explains your difficulties. SHM is inescapably mathematical. There is no point that I can see in trying to teach it to students who can't – yet – follow the mathematics. They won't be able to appreciate its beauty and they'll be confused. I'm sorry if that seems unsympathetic; in fact I'm anything but unsympathetic: you seem to have been put in a difficult position and you are trying to do your best.

Comment: So how do I proceed then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142800/discussion-between-philip-wood-and-thecuriousone).

Comment: It depends what you know. Do you, for example, know what $\frac{d_2 x}{dt^2}$ means? Can you show that $x=A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$ is the solution to the Newton's law equation $\frac{d_2 x}{dt^2}=-kx$, if we write $\omega^2$ instead of $k/m$ ? ['Chat' won't let me use *Latex* to write mathematical symbols properly, so I've gone back to comments.]

Comment: I do know differentiation and it’s graphical understanding but not integration.

Comment: So you know that if $x=A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$ in which $\omega$, $A$ and $\phi$ are constants, then $\frac{dx}{dt}=A\omega \cos(\omega t+\phi)$ and you can differentiate again to get $\frac{d_2 x}{dt^2}$ ?

Comment: Yes I know that very well.

Comment: That's brilliant. Then you can show that $x=A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$ fits the Newton's law equation $m\frac{d_2x}{dt^2}=–kx$ provided that $\omega^2=k/m$

Comment: Ok sir thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The projection of the (two-dimensional) uniform circular motion of an object onto a (one-dimensional) axis is an exact mathematical analog to simple harmonic motion.  Uniform circular motion is identical to rotation about an axis with constant angular velocity, $\omega$.  You can see the details of this connection, e.g., [in pp 2-5 of these notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y-fbNo_ZChuHI8CLTJogCveZ8kTwBu3Q/view?usp=share_link).

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have this time plot .

[image]

first we identify this plot as a $~f(t)=A\,\sin(a\,t+\phi)~$ . To "measure"  the
period $~T~$ of the function, we obtain the zero-crossing of $~f(t_i)=0~$

$$ T=4.562388980-1.420796327=3.141592653$$

thus the function is now  :
$$f(t)=A\,\sin(\underbrace{\frac{2\pi}{T}}_{a}\,t+\phi)\tag 1$$

we defined a new parameter , call it angular velocity which is:

$$\frac{2\,\pi}{T}:=\omega~,\text{unit}~[\frac 1s]$$

Eq. (1) is also the solution of SHM

$$\ddot x+\omega^2\,x=0$$

Comment: Why are you assuming a becomes 2pi/T?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for this answer . Put the data $~\frac{2\pi}{T}~$ you obtain a=2 , thus $f(t)=\sin(a\,t+\phi)$ my Ansatz

Answer (score -1):

In linear motion angular frequency makes no immediate sense, it is just $2\cdot\pi\cdot f$ but since it is in the formula for harmonic motion it is easier to write $sin(\omega t)$ instead of $sin(2\pi f t)$  You can proof, that the linear motion is the same as the projection of uniform circular motion.